# Converting .each() to for loop jQuery

Tags: jquery

The current function takes a long time to loop through and affects the performance of the app. Can someone help me to convert each() function to for loop? Thanks

```
  $('.scrollable tr:last').find('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').each(function() {
        var pos = $(this).closest('td').prevAll().length;
        var tot = 0;
        var that = this;
        var temp = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().find('td:eq(' + pos + ')').find('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').each(function() {
            tot += +$(this).val();
            $(that).val(tot);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you should look into why the code takes so long. Don't think changing to a for loop will change much on the performance.

Comment: you could try adding a class to the inputs you want to select, that would be much quicker than selecting them via name.

Comment: if you add unique IDs to each inputs, and fetch it with `['id^=resuource_week']` because ID selectors are faster than class!

Comment: The performance is too poor because you are querying the DOM tree many times using find() often. Instead use proper CSS selectors to make it efficient. Share your HTML to provide you a  better solution

Comment: I have added the class to tr:last and instead of find() I am selecting this class. Now it has better performance. Thank you @mohamedrias for suggestion.

Comment: As @mohamedrias has pointed out your performance is being impacted by the number of DOM tree queries you're running. Some of them are quite unnecessary, for example `$(that).val(tot)` does not have to be within the inner `.each()` loop. If you showed us your markup and what it is you're are trying to do, **we might suggested better code**.

Comment: @IrecoGnizedYou There is one more error in your code inside the inner $.each loop. Please check my answer for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, You are doing two things wrong:

1) You are querying the DOM tree often using find(). Instead use proper CSS selectors

2) Inside the $.each() loop

```
  var temp = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().find('td:eq(' + pos +  ')').find('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').each(function() {
                tot += +$(this).val();
                $(that).val(tot);
            });
```

You are updating the value of `input` quite often, which is not required. Inside the for each loop, each time you use `$(that).val(tot);` the DOM tree is affected.

As the `tot` is assigned to a variable, outside he `each()` loop, put `$(this).val(tot)` which will give you the same result in an efficient way.

3) This is not a performance improvement, instead a code error:

You are using `tot += +$(this).val();`

but it should be `tot += $(this).val();`inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't this do the trick?

```
$('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').each(function() {
        var pos = $(this).closest('td').prevAll().length;
        var tot = 0;
        var that = this;
        var temp = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().find('td:eq(' + pos + ')').find('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').each(function() {
            tot += +$(this).val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your markup it is difficult to tell what your code is doing but the following guess might help you figure out a better way to re-write your code:

```
$('.scrollable tr').last().find('tr').each(function(i, v) {
    var that = $(this),
        tot = that.find('td').map(function(k,l){ return 0; }).get();
    that.prevAll().each(j,u) {
        tot = $(this).find('td').map(function(k,l) { 
            return +$(l).find('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').val() + tot[k];
        }).get();
    });
    that.find('td').each(function(j,u) {
        $(u).find('input[name="resource_week_value[]"]').val( tot[ j ] );
    });
});
```